# Blazor Calendar Connection with Google Calendar

Tags: c#, blazor, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want from my Server-Side Blazor App to connect with Google Calendar and Post my Events

Hello everyone! I've tried many ways and tutorials but i am always having problems with redirects , access token saves , posting. I want if its possible from a single button to sync with google calendar and post my Event on it. I got the credentials needed and scopes from console.I am using some of the below code and i am trying to get how i can fit all that code to solve my problem.

Some of my code that i've made so far:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and include your code not images of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The Google .Net client library does not support Blazor authorization.  see [1427](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1427)

You will need to drop the client library and code it yourself.